# ASP.NET MVC 5 Bundling feature

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

Does bundling (.js and .css) happen for each request? Or they will be created one time and cached for next requests?

When does it create?

Any affect on server CPU usage?

Comment: Commenting, as this is an assumption. Bundle is built first time when it is requested, further it is cached. The cache is bound to the files that are included. Whenever any of them are modified the bundle is rebuilt again.

Comment: Words above requires research, however, according to logic and behaviour that is observed, it acts exactly like this.

Comment: It has no a big effect on CPU as this is solely reading files (HDD task, inexpensive) and concatenation of strings (RAM task)

Comment: Thanks @Oybek but do you have any reference for your answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles are cached. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/bundling-and-minifying-in-asp-net-mvc) is the reference where it is said. Obviously, they are built only once per set of files.

Further, according to my own experience, when I simply replace files in the server, bundle gets rebuilt, which allows us to assume that cache is dependent on file system.

Finally, having stuff cached, we reduce the load on hardware.

Bundling is primarily HDD and RAM task, thus, CPU is not heavily involved. You may even think that CPU is out of this process. Of course if you have bundles that end up to 1 GB javascript file, you will notice some performance shifts on a server side.

If you have a 1 GB Javascript file, you have other issues.